# tribe_get_start_time displays the current date and time on other post types than tribe_events

Tags: posts, date-time, the-events-calendar

i am displaying posts selected by an ACF relationship (with object format) on a page, including custom posts like tribe_events.
I want to display the date and time on the tribe_events posts, but not on the other posts. I am using this code below. It displays correctly the start date and time of the tribe_events, but it also displays the current date and time on the other posts. What can i don to have the date and time only on the tribe_events posts ? Thanks ;-)

```
<?php
global $post;
$posts = get_field( 'relationship' );
if( $posts ): 

foreach( $posts as $p ):
setup_postdata( $p );

// Display the date of the event
$p_event = tribe_get_start_time ( $p->ID, 'j F à H \h i' );

if ( $p_event ) { 
    echo $p_event;          
}
else '';
endforeach;
endif; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to solve this. First coming to mind are checking via [`is_singular()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_singular/) or [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/). Using the latter you could write

```
foreach( $posts as $p ):
    setup_postdata( $p );

    $post_type = get_post_type($p);

    if ($post_type === Tribe__Events__Main::POSTTYPE) {
    //or: if ($post_type === 'tribe_events') {

        // Display the date of the event
        $p_event = tribe_get_start_time ( $p->ID, 'j F à H \h i' );

        if ( $p_event ) { 
            echo $p_event;          
        }
        else '';
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Thanks @kero, i get it. I used the get_post_type solution you proposed and it works perfectly. ;-)

Comment: You're welcome! Using `get_post_type()` is cleaner here in my opinion. If in the future other post types will be in the list as well, you can then use `switch` e.g.

Comment: What do you mean by "switch" ? And also a noob question, why that function needs 3 equal signs (means identical if i'm correct), what is the difference between "=", "==" and "===" ?

Comment: [`switch()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) is a control structure. About the equal signs: you are correct. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063480/the-3-different-equals) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp). I prefer using `===` when possible, here it is no problem as both are strings

Comment: I'll inspect that. Thank you again for all those clarifications ;-)